# high-throughput, transactional usage of Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, throughput

I have scoured the Internet, posted to the Spring forums, and read nearly the whole of the online documentation, but I cannot figure out whether Spring Integration can process more than one message within a single multi-resource (JTA) transaction.  This is critical for my purposes, in order to get the throughput necessary.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  (And a little guidance on how to make it work would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 2):

Once a transaction is started, as long as you don't pass a thread boundary all work will remain in that transaction.

This means that, if your transaction manager supports multi-resource transactions and you avoid introducing concurrency within the transaction, you will be OK.

In other words: it depends, but it is possible.